# JS setInterval() работает только если расписать функцию целиком

Tags: javascript, функции, setinterval

Обучаюсь по книжке Js for Kids (12 глава). В упражнении нужно сделать машинку, которая "едет" по экрану. Никак не могу понять, почему закомментированная строка не работает? Сама книга этот момент не освящает, а гугл только еще больше запутал.

```
let Car = function (x, y) {
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
};

Car.prototype.draw = function () {
    let carHtml = '<img src="images/car.png">';

    this.carElement = $(carHtml);

    this.carElement.css({
        position: "absolute",
        left: this.x,
        top: this.y
    });

    $("body").append(this.carElement);
};

Car.prototype.moveRight = function () {
    this.x += 5;
    this.carElement.css({
        left: this.x,
        top: this.y
    });
};

let nissan = new Car(100, 200);

nissan.draw();

// nissanMoveTimer = setInterval(nissan.moveRight, 1000); // Cannot read property 'css' of undefined
nissanMoveTimer = setInterval(function () { nissan.moveRight(); }, 1000); // Рабочий код

setTimeout(function () { clearInterval(nissanMoveTimer);}, 5000);
```

Comment: Моё понимание кода:
setInterval(nissan.moveRight, 1000); // Вызывать метод moveRight объекта nissan каждую секунду.

setInterval(function () { nissan.moveRight(); }, 1000); // Создать функцию, разово выполняющую код внутри метода moveRight и вызывать её каждую секунду.

Смысл одинаковый, второй вариант даже кажется избыточным, однако работает только он. 
С последней строкой, где clearInTerval, ситуация такая же - работает, только если расписать function () {func}; в первом аргументе.

Comment: `setInterval(nissan.moveRight.bind(nissan), 1000)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вам правильно указали в комментариях о потери контекста вызова.
Что происходить на самом деле

```
setInterval(nissan.moveRight, 1000);
```

это эквивалент

```
let func = nissan.moveRight;

setInterval(func, 1000);
```

теперь вызов func() потерял контекст (nissan) так как вызывается напрямую. И this
внутри func() уже window или null в зависимости от мода

Comment: Благодарю, проблема прояснилась.

Answer (score 0):

Потому что setInterval имеет синтаксис:

```
let timerId = setTimeout(func|code, [delay], [arg1], [arg2], ...)
```

где **func|code** - это
функция или строка кода для выполнения. Обычно это функция. По историческим причинам можно передать и строку кода, но это не рекомендуется.

---

Надеюсь, понятно